# Underwater Post Process Using Unreal Engine 4 Water Plugin?

Tags: unreal-4, water

I'm using a custom water body from Unreal Engine 4's water plugin and I'd really like the screen to turn blue as soon as the first person camera goes underwater. I tried putting just a normal post process that surrounds the whole water body and colored it blue but the transition between on land and underwater is pretty bad, especially with the waves, so the player could just stand at a certain height in the water and see the entire ocean without post process. So, I was wondering, is there any way to make the water have a dynamic post process that changes shape depending on the waves for a clean transition? Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm on 4.26.2 and my water body lake doesn't show the postprocess underwater effect like I'm seeing it should out of the box in tutorial videos. I, like you, created a postprocess volume and got the effect I want, but it's not going to work well with waves.

Comment: @Nostrildumbass Sorry, still haven't found anything out yet, there doesn't seem to be much documentation on water at all.